# How can the direction angle for any vector be between $0$ and $π$ radians only?

Tags: linear-algebra

This doubt in regarding the direction angles of a vector. According to Wikipedia, the direction angles of a vector are always between 0 and π radians. How is that possible?

Consider this, $-3i -2j$, shouldn't this vector form an angle greater than $π$ with the positive direction of the x - axis

It would be great if someone clarified this doubt.

thanks!
This is the article from Wikipedia that I was referring to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0wXy.png

Comment: That article has to do with direction cosines; their only concern is measuring the amount of contribution that the positive axis makes toward the vector. Since that contribution depends only on the cosine of the angle between the positive axis and the vector, we can take the "shortest path" to the vector.

Comment: Note that in three dimensions, there's no obvious preferred direction to count the angle as there is in two dimensions (and even then it's only a convention).

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The domain of any $\alpha$ can be between $(0, 2 \pi)$ in 2d for all vectors. In 3d limit  angles to $(i,j,k) ...(0, \pi) , (0, \pi/2),(0,  \pi/2).$

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article is talking about director cosines of a vector, not the director angles of the vector.

Since the cosine is an even function, it means that the sign of the angle does not matter
$$\cos(a) = \cos(-a)$$

So the equation can be either

$$\cos^2(a) + \cos^2(b) + \cos^2(c) = \cos^2(-a) + \cos^2(-b) + \cos^2(-c) = 1$$
where

$$0 \le a, b, c \le \pi $$